# Algebra Mixture Problem Inquiry

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem : Tank A contains a mixture of 10 gallons water and 5 gallons pure alcohol. Tank B has 12 gallons water and 3 gallons alcohol. How many gallons should be taken from each tank and combined in order to obtain an 8 gallon solution containing 25% alcohol by volume?

From the book, 2 equations were derived based from the problem :

Equation 1 -> x + y = 8 & Equation 2 -> 0.3333x + 0.2y = 0.25(8)

My question : What is the formula used to get the 0.3333 and 0.2? **Why or how is the formula designed like that?** (Note : My question is not how to answer the problem.)

My thoughts / analysis : To get 0.33333, the fraction must be 1/3. So from the first tank, we have 10 gallons of water and 5 gallons of pure alcohol.

So, 5 / (10 + 5) = 5 / 15 = 1/3 = 0.33333. If we used that on 2nd tank, we will get the 0.2

So, If we are to put it into words :

**Mixture of gal. of water and pure alcohol = x gallons of alcohol / (x gallons of alcohol + x gallons of water)**. The question is why or how is that the formula for mixing the gallons of alcohol and water? In my mind it should be just an addition between the 2, water + alcohol = mixture.

Sorry If the question is silly but thanks in advance for those who can explain it clear. God bless.

Comment: In your penultimate paragraph, you are using $x$ in two different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authors of the book are implicitly making the following definitions:

- Let $x$ be the volume in gallons of the solution from tank A that is placed in the mixture.
- Let $y$ be the volume in gallons of the solution from tank B that is placed in the mixture.

The equation $x + y = 8$ means that the $8$ gallons of the mixture are formed by combining $x$ gallons of the solution in tank A with $y$ gallons of tank B.

Since tank A contains $10$ gallons of water and $5$ gallons of alcohol, $1/3$ of the solution in tank A is alcohol.  Thus, if we place $x$ gallons of the solution from tank A in the mixture, we place $x/3$ gallons of alcohol in the mixture.

Since tank B contains $12$ gallons of water and $3$ gallons of alcohol, $1/5$ of the solution in tank B is alcohol.  Thus, if we place $y$ gallons of the solution from tank B in the mixture, we place $y/5$ gallons of alcohol in the mixture.

Since the final mixture is $25\%$ alcohol, $1/4$ of the eight gallons in the mixture is composed of alcohol.

Therefore, the equation for the amount of alcohol in the final mixture is 
$$\frac{x}{3} + \frac{y}{5} = \frac{8}{4}$$
The second equation in the book expresses this using decimals rather than fractions.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. But what I am confused is how the 1/3 is determined from 10 gallons of water and 5 gallons of alcohol. From seeing and reading the 2 components mixed in that tank, you can't just simply state that "oh, mixing 10 gal. of water and 5 gal. of alcohol will result to 1/3 mixture". So back to the question, why is it 5 / (10 + 5) -> x / (x +y). [If we let x - alcohol and y = water for that tank "only". Not considering the other equation and variables, focusing only on that tank first.] Sorry, I really can't just get the thing out of my mind.

Comment: We get $1/3$ since $5$ of the $15$ gallons in the tank are alcohol.  As you said, $\frac{5}{5 + 10} = \frac{5}{15} = \frac{1}{3}$.